# Any way to catch when xp_readerrorlog fails?

Tags: sql-server-2016, error-handling, error-log

I'm trying to query the ErrorLog files, but it sometimes fails on some of my servers.
For some reason a file go missing from time to time.
 I do not know why. I do not think that I deleted the file :-).
Worse, SQL Server "crash" with this error

```
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 60
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

If I run

```
EXEC master..xp_readerrorlog 999
```

I do get a proper error:

```
Msg 22004, Level 16, State 1, Line 63
xp_readerrorlog() returned error 2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

I have tried many things; TRY-Catch block, a separate sproc to do the insert and dynamic SQL. They all eat my error message.

Here is my code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 

DROP TABLE if EXISTS #ReportSQLErrorLogs

CREATE TABLE #ReportSQLErrorLogs (
    row_id BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), 
    log_date datetime NULL,
    processinfo nvarchar(16) NULL,
    ProcessText NVARCHAR(2048) NULL,
    CurrentLogNum TINYINT NULL
)

DECLARE @NumErrorLogs INT, @CurrentLogNum INT
SET @CurrentLogNum = 0

-- Get total number of log files from registry
EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'NumErrorLogs', @NumErrorLogs OUTPUT
SELECT @NumErrorLogs = ISNULL(@NumErrorLogs, 6) -- NULL in registry entry for Error Log files mean default of 6 value

WHILE @CurrentLogNum < @NumErrorLogs BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #ReportSQLErrorLogs ( log_date, processinfo, ProcessText )
    EXEC master..xp_readerrorlog @CurrentLogNum
    --PRINT @CurrentLogNum
    RAISERROR ('at %i', 10, 1, @CurrentLogNum) WITH NOWAIT

    UPDATE #ReportSQLErrorLogs SET CurrentLogNum=@CurrentLogNum WHERE CurrentLogNum IS NULL
    SELECT @CurrentLogNum = @CurrentLogNum + 1
END
```

And bonus points if you happen to know why errorlog files can go missing.

Comment: You could just read the error log files (which are just plain text) outside of SQL Server using C#, PowerShell, etc. by only opening the files that exist instead of relying on sync between registry config and actual files on disk. Plenty of ways they can get out of sync - manual delete, a server with settings for 6 errorlog files but the service hasn't restarted 6 times yet, etc.